# Running Total Inventory Slow Performance - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an inventory table with a Running Quantity column grouping by the [LocGroup], see image 1

[image: Image 1]

I want to get the Total Inventory for each day and then the LocGroup breakdown see final result Image 2.
Example: I can see on the 2019-10-21 Total Inventory was 11 and breakdown was GroupA -1 and GroupB 12

[image: Image 2]

I have created code that works but when I run on 100,000+ records it is really slow, is there a better way to do this?

I'm guessing current way slow as and b.[EntryDate] <= a.[EntryDate] is summing everything each time.

My current code:

```
with cte_1 -- Get Total Stock Position not Grouped
as
(
    SELECT [CmpID],[EntryDate] ,[ProductID],[ColourCode]
    ,SUM([Quantity]) OVER(PARTITION BY [CmpID],[ProductID],[ColourCode] ORDER BY [EntryDate]) [TOTAL Running Quantity]
    FROM [dbo].[Inventory]
)
,cte_2 -- Get Stock Breakdown for each Day from cte_1
as
(
    SELECT a.[CmpID],a.[EntryDate],a.[ProductID],a.[ColourCode],a.[TOTAL Running Quantity],b.[LocGroup],MAX(b.[EntryDate]) as [MaxDate]
    FROM cte_1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Inventory] b
    on a.[CmpID] = b.[CmpID]
    and a.[ProductID] = b.[ProductID]
    and a.[ColourCode] = b.[ColourCode]
    and b.[EntryDate] <= a.[EntryDate]
    GROUP BY a.[CmpID],a.[EntryDate],a.[ProductID],a.[ColourCode],a.[TOTAL Running Quantity],b.[LocGroup]
)

SELECT a.[CmpID],a.[EntryDate],a.[ProductID],a.[ColourCode],a.[TOTAL Running Quantity],a.[LocGroup],b.[Running Quantity]
FROM cte_2 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Inventory] b
on a.[CmpID] = b.[CmpID]
and a.[ProductID] = b.[ProductID]
and a.[ColourCode] = b.[ColourCode]
and a.[LocGroup] = b.[LocGroup]
and b.[EntryDate] = a.[MaxDate]
ORDER BY a.[ColourCode], a.[EntryDate], a.[LocGroup]
```

Comment: The _actual execution plan_ is a good place to start with many performance issues. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question. Complete DDL, including indexes, should also be provided. A [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) might help, but you haven't provided enough information to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating your stats in real time on all data will always be expensive and will get worse as your data grows.  Better to keep a running statistic in another table and modify those stats as records are inserted into your table.  Like when you insert a new row into your table, if that day doesn't exist in your statistics table then insert a record for that day.  and if the day already existed in your statistics table then just update the counts for that day.